# SQLite 3.6.21: "Squeezing" out NULL values with a unique column value

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite 3.6.21, I would like to update a column in a table.

The goal is to "squeeze out" NULLs from a column if there is only 1 unique real value in that column.  If LastName contained "Smith", "Johnson", and a NULL, then do nothing.

For example:

```
create table foo (FirstName char(20), LastName char(20));
insert into foo values ('Joe', 'Smith');
insert into foo values ('Susan', NULL);
insert into foo values ('Shirley', 'Smith');
insert into foo values ('Kevin', NULL);
```

Since there is only one last name, I want to replace the NULLs with Smith.  I have tried this without success.  It ends up replacing the whole column with NULLs.

```
UPDATE foo
SET LastName = 
    ( CASE
         WHEN ((select count(distinct LastName) from foo) = 1)  THEN (SELECT distinct LastName from foo)
         ELSE LastName
      END
    );
```

EDIT:

I'm executing this in Python using the following code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

'''
con = lite.connect('test.db')
names = (
    ('Joe', 'Smith'),
    ('Susan', None),
    ('Shirley', 'Smith'),
    ('Kevin', None),
)


squeezecmd = "UPDATE foo SET LastName = (CASE WHEN ((select count(distinct LastName) from foo) = 1) THEN (SELECT distinct LastName from foo) ELSE LastName END)"

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE foo(FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT)")
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO foo VALUES(?, ?)", names)

    cur.execute(squeezecmd)
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print row
```

Comment: Your query worked for me  [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e32b5/1)

Comment: That website utilizes version 3.8.5 of SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python reorders the "SELECT distinct LastName from foo" so that the NULL is the first value.  SQL provides "Smith" as the first value.  To ignore the NULL I changed that line to

```
...THEN (SELECT distinct LastName from foo where LastName is NOT NULL)
```

EDIT:

Copy from SQL console:

```
sqlite>
sqlite> SELECT distinct LastName from foo;
Smith

sqlite>
```

Copy from Python:

```
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT distinct LastName from foo")
    answer = cur.fetchall()
    print answer
```

Results in

```
[(None,), (u'Smith',)]
```

Comment: It's Python doing that, as opposed to a version difference? I'm very surprised by that -- `fetchall()` should return rows in the same order SQLite handed them off in, and a subquery would never touch the Python runtime to start with.

Comment: From my testing yes, it is python doing it.  Very unexpected

Comment: To some extent, I find that literally unbelievable -- the Python runtime has no access to subquery contents. On the other hand, undefined behavior is just that -- allowed to vary based on things as random as memory alignment or random number generator seeding, and I could see how a runtime container could have an impact there. It might be interesting to track down the mechanism, and determine how deterministic the behavior in question really is. Certainly, though, adding the IS NOT NULL is the right fix.

Comment: That said, unless you've already done that work to track down a deterministic cause, claiming that you have one ("Python reorders[...]") is a bit of a reach.

Comment: I haven't researched it further.  However I added the outputs from both systems to show why I said that

Comment: And the console is also 3.6.21? I'll try to take a shot at reproducing that result when I get a chance, and tracking down the underlying cause of that variance (if, in fact, it's reproducible on my platform; if it's actually a result of undefined behavior, that may not be the case).